# How to use reduce method by loadash for nested/complex object

Tags: reactjs, nested-json

I have data like this

```
const faq = 
{
Question1:{
   question:’Question1’,
   answer: {
       Answer1_1: {
          answer: ‘Answer1_1’
       },
       Answer1_2: {
          answer: ‘Answer1_2’
       }
    }
},
Question2:{
   question:’Question2’,
   answer: {
       Answer2_1: {
          answer: ‘Answer2_1’
       },
       Answer2_2: {
          answer: ‘Answer2_2’
       }
    }
}
}
```

And the expected result I want is

```
[
    {
    question: ’Question1’
    answer: [‘Answer1_1’, ‘Answer1_2’]
    }, 
    {
    question: ’Question2’
    answer: [‘Answer2_1’, ‘Answer2_2’]
    }
]
```

From what I understood I made a function like this:

```
const convertQuestionTypesToMap = compose(
    reduce(
        (map, {question, answer}) => ({...map, [question]: question}),
        {}
    ),
    map(([question, value]) => value),
    toEntries
);
```

I am not getting the expected result. Can anyone correct my function?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it only using Javascript using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

#### Using Array.map

```js
const data = { Question1: { question: "Question1", answer: { Answer1: { answer: "Answer1_1", }, Answer2: { answer: "Answer1_2", }, }, }, Question2: { question: "Question2", answer: { Answer1: { answer: "Answer2_1", }, Answer2: { answer: "Answer2_2", }, }, }, };

const output = Object.values(data).map(({ question, answer }) => {
    return {
        question,
        answer: Object.values(answer).map(({ answer }) => answer),
    };
});

console.log(output);
```

#### Using Array.reduce

```js
const data = { Question1: { question: "Question1", answer: { Answer1: { answer: "Answer1_1", }, Answer2: { answer: "Answer1_2", }, }, }, Question2: { question: "Question2", answer: { Answer1: { answer: "Answer2_1", }, Answer2: { answer: "Answer2_2", }, }, }, };

const output = Object.values(data).reduce((prev, { question, answer }) => {
  prev.push({
    question,
    answer: Object.values(answer).reduce((prevVal, { answer }) => {
      prevVal.push(answer);
      return prevVal;
    }, []),
  });
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @kona B, check this out !!

Comment: Thank you so much Amila Senadheera. This solution worked. Wanted to know if we can use 'reduce' method in this case

Comment: @kona B, You can use reduce as well. But the preferred one, in this case, is map. reduce is used to convert a set of values to a single value (converge data). I have updated the answer! can you please mark this as the answer once you validate it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `for in loop`;

First `for in loop` for push the `question` in main array and second `for in loop` for get `answer` in child objects

```
 let newArr = [];
    let arr = [];
    for (key in Data) {
      //get the question from each object
      let question = Data[key].question; 
      arr = []; 
      for (child in Data[key].answer) { 
        //get answer from child object
        arr.push(Data[key].answer[child].answer); 
      }
      newArr.push({
        question: question,
        answer: arr
      });
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr), 'newArr');
```

Comment: Thank you for a very quick reply. This solution worked but I wanted to know to use 'reduce' method.